# Tunnel SSH: access a server blocked by firewall through another server

Tags: linux, ssh, tunnel

I have 1 pc and 2 servers.

Each device has a user associated with it:

- pc (10.0.0.10) -> pc_user
- server1 (10.0.0.146) -> server1_user
- server2 (192.168.0.3) -> server2_user

There is a firewall blocking everything from "pc" to "server2".

The goal is to acess "server2" from "pc" through a SSH tunnel to "server1".

How can I do it?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/368266/ssh-through-multiple-hosts-using-proxycommand is a prior duplicate (actually, a more complex form of the question, but any answer for it is also an answer for this) moved to ServerFault because it, like this question, was off-topic on StackOverflow. (I'd actually argue SuperUser over ServerFault -- SSH is end-user software every bit as much as it's a system administration tool -- but in any event this is in no way a question about software development).

Comment: (...if you were trying to write your own SSH client, ie. with paramiko or Jsch, *then* it'd be a StackOverflow question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using openssh:

**TRIVIAL WAY**

```
PC> ssh server1_user@server1
server1> ssh server2_user@server2
```

**PROXY WAY**

Get a `netcat` on server1, if you can't install one, you can try to statically compile one (check busybox), download one (find server1 and OS version and check it's repos). If you have python/perl, there are "script implementations" of the command.

On your `~/.ssh/config` file add:

```
Host server1
  HostName 10.0.0.146
  User server1_user

Host server2
  ProxyCommand ssh -C -q server1 /<server1_path_to>/nc 192.168.0.3 22 
  User server2_user
```

`ssh server2` will prompt for both passwords, if you're not using key authentication.

Since OpenSSH 5.4 netcat is not required for proxying

```
Host server2
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p server1
  User server2_user
```

**TUNNEL WAY**

```
PC TTY1> ssh -L 2222:192.168.0.3:22 server1_user@server1
PC TTY2> ssh server2_user@localhost -p 2222
```

Comment: You are missing the proxy-tunnel way, using `ssh -W` :-)

Comment: Yup, found about it yesterday, by Charles Duffy comment